# Isn't instantiating an object of type Interface illegal?

Tags: java, interfaces

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1061775/2124148) describing how Spring for Java works instantiates an object of type Interface which is **illegal** yet it received 21 upvotes. Why is this answer upvoted for illegal behavior?

Spring contains (as Skaffman rightly pointed out) a MVC framework. To explain in short here are my inputs. Spring supports segregation of service layer, web layer and business layer, but what it really does best is "injection" of objects. So to explain that with an example consider the example below:

```
public interface FourWheel
{
   public void drive();
}

public class RoadTrip
{
    private FourWheel myCarForTrip;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a instantiation in his answer.

Comment: @tkausl   `private FourWheel myCarForTrip;`

Comment: Thats not a instantiation though...

Comment: Did you mean to ask this on Stack Overflow's *meta* site?  We're a *software design* site, and people can vote however they like.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, because I wanted to know why the following behavior was accepted by the community, and apparently not illegal (and downvoted). Until a few moments later of research did I realize that I was mistaking declarations and instantiations.

Comment: You can instantiate an interface using any class that *implements that interface.*  The underlying type will be `AnyClass`, but only the members declared in the interface will be available to your code.

Answer (score 2):

What the user performed was a *declaration* of the interface, but not an instantiation. An instantiation would be as follows:

```
Fourwheel myFour = new FourWheel();
```

Declarations of interface types are legal because class types that implement that interface can be assigned to these declarations, shown below:

```
FourWheel newFour = new Sedan();
```

Alternatively, an anonymous inner class may be used:

```
Fourwheel myFour = new FourWheel() { public void say(){ System.out.println("Anonymous inner class");}};
```

Comment: What is "anonymous" about that assignment?  Isn't `Sedan` a concrete type?

Comment: That's the declaration of a *field* (or *member variable*), and Sedan is not anonymous.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4587432/2124148

Comment: @bigstones According to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4587432/2124148) , "what you did above was create an Anonymous class that implements the interface." and it follows the same structure.

Comment: @JossieCalderon: [jjnguy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2598/jjnguy) makes the same complaint in that answer, and I see that they're splitting hairs over there.  Yes, technically, you can't instantiate an interface, but you *can* instantiate a type that implements that interface, which essentially amounts to the same thing.  It's not an anonymous type over there either.  Sorry.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But there was yet another answer that said it was, and it received **55** upvotes? (Don't worry, I'll be asking that in meta.)

Comment: I think you might be overestimating the power of voting to identify a correct answer.  If your premise is that a high number of votes is equivalent to a *completely correct answer,*  I can assure you that the correlation there is fairly low, because people can and do cast votes however they like.  This is especially true of posts with a high number of views (like that one), as bikeshedding becomes involved, and *everyone has an opinion.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JossieCalderon: It would seem that we're both victims of the wacky terminology that is sometimes used in Java.  What they're referring to over there when they say "anonymous" is **a class that implements an interface without using the `implements` keyword.**  It looks like some form of "duck typing," but I'm not enough of an expert in Java to be sure.  [This guy](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/anonymous-class-interface/) says that you can't even use the term "anonymous class" in this way unless you also include the word "inner."  So, pick your poison.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've edited my answer further. This explains why a class is called "anonymous": It implements an interface, has no name, and the `implements` keyword is not used because it has no name.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Further, if no interfaces are used, the anonymous inner class is really a subclass overriding a superclass's method.

Comment: Apparently the class is considered anonymous because it is nested.  Oh, well.  Time and again, my C# knowledge fails to illuminate Java; they really are different languages.  C# anonymous classes *don't have names at all,* and they don't have to be nested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41075/discussion-between-jossie-calderon-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not anonymous because it's nested; it's anonymous because it's a nameless. That code snippet creates an instance of a nameless class that implements the FourWheel interface.

Comment: @Doval: *Then why does it have a name?*  `FourWheel`

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's the name of the interface, not of the class (which is anonymous and nameless)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've also listed a nice description for you in chat. Please don't ignore it.